# Ember: add entire object to controller

Tags: ember.js

Is there an easy way to add controller properties directly from a javascript object?

As opposed to having to manually specify each and every query param I want to use in 3 places: queryParams, QP controller properties, and route queryParams[key].refreshModel = true...I just want to maintain this stuff in ONE object and update it to all those places:

```
const cfg = {
    defaultQueryParams: {
        q: null,
        paging: '18',
        search_sort: 'relevance',
        search_title: null,
        search_page: null,
        filter_breadcrumb: [],
        filter_price: [],
        filter_size_apparel: [], 
        filter_color: [] 
    }
};
```

In the controller I tried:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: Object.keys(cfg.defaultQueryParams), // works great!

    init() {  
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.addObject(cfg.defaultQueryParams); // doesn't work: "this.addObjects is not a function"
        // same with addObjects, setObjects
    },
    ...
});
```

I also tried iterating over the JS object and using the setter.  It works for strings, but not for the empty arrays:

```
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(cfg.defaultQueryParams)) {  
        this.set(key, value);
    }
```

The arrays are added as properties but in the console are undefined rather than Array[0]

Am I way off base in wanting to do this, or wanting to do it this way?

Go easy! Ember newb! :D

Comment: "The arrays are added as properties but in the console are undefined rather than Array[0]". How are you checking this?

Comment: console.log(this); from within one of my controller actions.  I can expand the Class in the console and see it says "filter_breadcrumb: undefined"  When I instead add filter_breadcrumb: [], ... directly to the controller and do the same I see: filter_breadcrumb: Array[0]

Comment: Have you considered to use a mixin?

Comment: I actually tried creating a mixin and importing it into the route and the controller.  Couple issues.  First, I don't want the properties like q, paging, search_sort, etc. to be set on the route (only the controller).  And there's a namespace issue with queryParams.  For example, the controller needs an array called queryParams,  and in order to set refreshModel=true, the route wants an array of hashes called queryParams.  So I can't put queryParams in the mixin, they have to be kept separately for route and controller.

Answer (score 1):

There is `setProperties` method for all objects in ember.

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4d76d0adfe4cad8b690a4ff435286ec4) and [setProperties](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_setProperties)

Comment: Thanks...I was hoping that would work, but I'm running into the same issue as I did when I tried to do a 'set' inside a loop.  Here's a twiddle to show what I mean: https://ember-twiddle.com/fb1680bfea201aeb4a0d886aafa3eed5?openFiles=templates.results.hbs%2C&route=%2Fresults%3Fpaging%3D24%26q%3Dfoo%26search_page%3D3%26search_sort%3Drelevance

Comment: Then, here's a twiddle that works because I set the cfg properties directly in the controller: https://ember-twiddle.com/b82c69819c5eb51171c6724960f880fe?openFiles=templates.results.hbs%2C&route=%2Fresults%3Ffilter_breadcrumb%3D%255B%2522Home%2520%253E%2520Kitchen%2520and%2520Bar%2522%252C%2522Home%2520%253E%2520Kitchen%2520and%2520Bar%2522%255D%26paging%3D24%26q%3Dfoo%26search_page%3D3

Comment: From what I can tell you can't set objects en-masse like this using setProperties, only strings.  Even if the objects have values.  Unless I am doing something wrong.